# Java - find position of a string in a List of storage object

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I guess the title of this questions says it all, or says nothing...
After couple of hours of googling, trying things and reinventing Java I decided to ask you.

I have this storage class:

```
class AppInfo implements Comparable<AppInfo > {
        private String appname = "";
        private String pname = "";
        private String versionName = "";
        //private int versionCode = 0;
        private Drawable icon;
        private String appdir = "";
        private String appSize = "";

        @Override
        public int compareTo(AppInfo other) {
            int compareAppsName = appname.compareToIgnoreCase(other.appname);

            return compareAppsName;
        }

    }
```

I do what I do and eventually I get a List filled with objects.
Everything works great, ListView is populated with the right data...

Now I want to search a string (a certain pname) and see if it exists in the List and if it does, what's its position in the list (its index).

Tried creating another list with only the data I need.. tried Lists, HashMaps, LinkedHashMap, 2 dimensional arrays/arrayList... nothing did the trick...
Also tried iterating the list but couldn't figure out how to handle the elements I got.

Hopefully I make some sense and that's even possible.

Disclosure: Please bear with me, I am kinda new in Java.

Comment: *"Please bare with me"* - no thanks :-)

Comment: @Stephen C LOL sorry about that. Honest mistake, not an invitation ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question, but if you want to find the indices of the list elements with the given pname value, you can do something like this:

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String panme = list.get(i).getPname();
    if (pname != null && pname.equals(expectedPname));
        indices.add(i);
    }
}
```

I just reread your question, and it sounds like you're only expecting the index to show up once.  Sorry for the confusion.  For that, you can use the same idea without the additional list:

```
int matchingIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String pname = list.get(i).getPname();
    if (pname != null && pname.equals(expectedPname));
        matchingIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted even before I saw the update... Excellent! Thank you :)

Comment: Not a problem; I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 2):

If you just wanting to check the pname string you could add a getter method to your AppInfo class e.g.

```
  public String getPname(){
    return pname ;
  }
```

then as you iterate through your list you can call .getPname to extract the string at the given position in the list.

m

Comment: Thanks but I don't have the given position... the position(index) is what i'm looking for... (in case the pname I have does exists in the List<AppInfo>

Comment: ok, the getter method will help you to identify if it exists in the list. you need to iterate through the list yourself and check each entry. You will get the position from your iterator variable.

Comment: Thanks, +1 your answer for the right direction and kindness :)